# Power series representation of an integral, centered at 1?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

We let $$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\ln(t)}{t-1} \,dt $$
I want to represent this integral as a power series centered at $1$. My initial strategy is to take a Taylor series of $\ln(t)$ and divide that by $(t-1)$. Then interchange summation and integral.  Is this strategy valid or am I making a mistake?

So    $\ln(t) = (t-1) - \frac{1}{2}(t-1)^2 +\frac{1}{3}(t-1)^3+\ .... $ = $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(t-1)^n$
Dividing by (t-1) gave me $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(t-1)^{n-1}$

Comment: Yes, that should work if you do it right.

Comment: Have you already tried just taking the power series directly? The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives you an easy way to compute the first derivative. Maybe the derivatives follow some kind of pattern? Note: I’m not implying that they necessarily do, just asking what you’ve tried.

Comment: @AJY I havent tried that yet, but I will now.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I did some working in the question

Comment: $\displaystyle-\operatorname{Li}_{2}\left(1 - x\right)$

Answer (score 1):

First, Let's try to solve the integral
$$\int^x_1 \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}$$
Let $y=x-1$($dx=dy$).
$$\int^{x-1}_0 \frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}dy =\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^{x-1}\frac{y^{n}}{y}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}(0-(-\frac{(x-1)^{n}}{n}))=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^{n}}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\int_1^x \frac{\log (t)}{t-1} \, dt$$

$$\log t=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(t-1)^n$$

$$\frac{\log t}{t-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(t-1)^{n-1}$$ $$\int_1^x \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (t-1)^{n-1}}{n} \, dx=\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-1)^n}{n^2}$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-1)^n}{n^2}$$